# I do not see the "Allow Launch" option in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, .desktop

Ubuntu 19.10
I created a .desktop file in my Desktop folder but I do not see the "Allow Launch" option when I right click on it. Why?

Not sure it's relevant but someone is going to ask so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Current Tasks
Type=Link
URL=https://workflowy.com
Icon=text-html
```

Comment: Is the `.desktop` file executable?

Comment: @waltinator yes, I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an exec directory. I have found that if you don't include a valid exec directory the Ubuntu won't let you make it executable and thus won't show the "Allow Launch" option.

the exec field is supposed to point to the script that runs your application (a .sh file usually)

for example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Exec=/directorytoyourapp/runscriptofyourapp.sh
Comment=Development Enviroment for Android APK
Terminal=false
Icon=/whateveraddresstoyouricon/icon.png
Type=Application
```

Comment: Thank you Marco, I found this out also while helping a friend. If the exec is not pointing to the exact file it fails to show the "Allow Launch" option in the context menu.